# Shopify Carrier Service API doesn't show dates

Tags: api, shopify, carrier

I have registered a carrier service using the Shopify API. Shopify requires max and min delivery dates to show rates on checkout. I am passing these fields. But now I don't want to show these days with my rates titles. Is this possible?

Now the rate is shown as follows:
Test Standard(2 to 5 Business days)

I want to show
Test Standard

How I can achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can. The passing of dates is not well documented either. Take for example weekends. And timezones. A lot of times you get silly results, like 0 business days, or 3-5 without proper weekends... go figure.

Comment: @mani did you ever get this resolved? I'm having a heck of a time figuring this API out.. I can't pass anything and have it show up as a Shipping Method.. Can you pass along any examples?

Answer (score 1):

We have passed these fields as follows

```
 $express['min_delivery_date'] =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00 -0000"; 
 $express['max_delivery_date'] =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00 -0000";
```

This way, they are not showing any days only the shipping name.

Comment: desperately trying to get this to work.. anyway you can pass along the JSON that you are sending for rates?  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the Min & Max dates are optional, if they are not included the (2 to 5 business days) is not shown.